# Keep getting undentified as a function value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a slight problem, and by slight I mean I've spent the entire day fiddling with this code and not going anywhere. What the problem is that I have these groups of radio buttons, and I want to get their value so that I can implement the chosen colour on the canvas element. I've figured out the part where I'm supposed to extract the value from the currently selected button, but the problem is that I cant get the value out of the function.

Here's the code. This part is the index.html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_settings.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="settings"><h1>Customise your game</h1>
    <form id="colorformsnake" name="colorformsnake" onchange="getRadioValSnake()"><label>Choose the snake color: <br/><br/>

        Green: <input type="radio" id="green" value="green" name="snakecolor"><br /><br />
        Red: <input type="radio" id="red" value="red" name="snakecolor" /><br /><br />
        Blue: <input type="radio" value="blue" id="blue" name="snakecolor"></label><br /><br/><br /></form>
    <form id="colorformbg" onchange="getRadioValBg()" name="colorformbg">
    <label>Choose the background color: <br /><br/>
        Gray: <input type="radio" id="gray" value="gray" name="bgcolor" checked><br /><br />
        White: <input type="radio" id="white" value="white" name="bgcolor"/><br /><br />
        Black: <input type="radio" value="black" id="black" name="bgcolor"></label><br /><br><br /></form>
    </div>
<script src="javascript/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/colorsettings.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/initial_config.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/draw.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/app.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This part is the initial part where the user chooses the wanted colours. I have the first group which is the snake colour and the second which is the background. Everything in this should be fine.

Here's the second part. This is colorsettings.js

```js
var snakecolor=" ";
var bgcolor="";

function getRadioValSnake()
{
    window.snakecolor=($('input[name="snakecolor"]:checked', '#colorformsnake').val());
    return snakecolor;
}

function getRadioValBg()
{
    window.bgcolor=($('input[name="bgcolor"]:checked', '#colorformbg').val());
    return bgcolor;
}

var snakecolorCurrent=getRadioValSnake();

console.log(snakecolorCurrent);
```

Now what I want to do is to take the selected colour and insert it into a variable, which will be passed to an another .js file. That part I think I can solve by myself. The thing that I've been struggling with is that when i try to call any of those 2 functions it just returns unidentified.

I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the scope of the function. I've been trying to find a problem similar to mine in order to not bother anyone on here but nothing seems to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Comment: why `window.snakecolor=..`? why not simply `snakecolor=...`

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks, but ive already tried doing it without window, i dont normally use it but ive tried it this time, unsuccessfully as you see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-Edit: Running snake color & bg :)

```js
  var snakecolorCurrent = "";
  var bgcolorCurrent = "";
  $("input[name='snakecolor']").change(function() {
    var snakecolor = $('input[name="snakecolor"]:checked');
    snakecolorCurrent = snakecolor.val();
    snakecolor = snakecolorCurrent;
    console.log(snakecolor);
    console.log(snakecolorCurrent);
    return snakecolor;
  });
  $("input[name='bgcolor']").change(function() {
    var bgcolor = $('input[name="bgcolor"]:checked');
    bgcolorCurrent = bgcolor.val();
    bgcolor = bgcolorCurrent;
    console.log(bgcolor);
    console.log(bgcolorCurrent);
    return bgcolor;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="colorformsnake" name="colorformsnake">
  <label>Choose the snake color:
    <br/>
    <br/> Green:
    <input type="radio" id="green" value="green" name="snakecolor">
    <br />
    <br /> Red:
    <input type="radio" id="red" value="red" name="snakecolor" />
    <br />
    <br /> Blue:
    <input type="radio" value="blue" id="blue" name="snakecolor">
  </label>
  <br />
  <br/>
  <br />
</form>
<form id="colorformbg" name="colorformbg">
  <label>Choose the background color:
    <br />
    <br/> Gray:
    <input type="radio" id="gray" value="gray" name="bgcolor" checked>
    <br />
    <br /> White:
    <input type="radio" id="white" value="white" name="bgcolor" />
    <br />
    <br /> Black:
    <input type="radio" value="black" id="black" name="bgcolor">
  </label>
  <br />
  <br>
  <br />
</form>
```

Comment: I'm on a bus and can't use the mobile snippet tool (doesn't seem to work that well) but I think it should look more like this

Comment: thanks for your answer! but for some strange reason, this returns undefined too when implemented..

Comment: Still on mobile, untested! :(

Comment: This seems to solve the undefined problem, thank you! Unfortunately, when i try to set the current value in a variable, it only sets the checked=''checked' value in it, it doesnt want to change. If i dont use checked then it displays undefined.. again, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I think there's an extra quote mark in error after checked. Remove it. I'll update.

Comment: @aleksxp You now have 2 variables of same value. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Don't know if you really need the form id .. Optional

Comment: Yeah the form id doesnt need to be there,ive tried various ways of sending data, ill remove it when i succeed with this.Hmm not quite what i need. What I want to get is when the getRadioValSnake function executes to return its current value in a form of a variable, or to set it in one. Now what happens to me is that only green works for the snake and grey for the background because those are marked as checked="checked". For example if i try to check red nothing displays. When i remove the checked="checked" property it displays undefined. By the way im checking this with console.log(). Thanks

Comment: Sorry if im not understandable .. English isnt my first language

Comment: Hi sorry I'm just out of a meeting, will have a look now

Comment: Ive also tried this, but it doesnt work. Still stuck to green.           function getRadioValSnake()
{
    snakecolor=($('input[name="snakecolor"]:checked', '#colorformsnake').val());
    currentcolor=snakecolor;
    if(currentcolor=='green'){return 'green'}
    if(currentcolor=='red'){return 'red'}
    if(currentcolor=='blue'){return 'blue'}
}

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. But how would i put the value that this returns in a variable that is outside of this function?

Comment: @aleksxp currentColor is outside the function

Comment: @aleksxp is there a reason why you have these inputs within forms? the input will update on change anyway, you don't need a form to trigger the change event? as shown here https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/s80f6gu8/

Comment: After some time, ive finally figured it out. I just needed to call a function to the value directly without a variable. Thank you so much!

Comment: @aleksxp ok, i think you mean without a function name? (just function() ) but never the less, you don't need a form unless you're submitting it for something.. (e.g. for validation ., to another page...etc.)

Answer (score 1):

so if declared variable in global scope then you do need to call it with `window`

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zzqv0hxx/)

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_settings.css">
<script src="javascript/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/colorsettings.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/initial_config.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/draw.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/app.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/ajax.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="settings"><h1>Customise your game</h1>
        <form id="colorformsnake" name="colorformsnake" onchange="getRadioValSnake()"><label>Choose the snake color: <br/><br/>

            Green: <input type="radio" id="green" value="green"  checked="checked" name="snakecolor"><br /><br />
            Red: <input type="radio" id="red" value="red" name="snakecolor" /><br /><br />
            Blue: <input type="radio" value="blue" id="blue" name="snakecolor"></label><br /><br/><br /></form>
        <form id="colorformbg" onchange="getRadioValBg()" name="colorformbg">
        <label>Choose the background color: <br /><br/>
            Gray: <input type="radio" id="gray" value="gray" name="bgcolor" checked="checked"><br /><br />
            White: <input type="radio" id="white" value="white" name="bgcolor"/><br /><br />
            Black: <input type="radio" value="black" id="black" name="bgcolor"></label><br /><br><br /></form>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

js:

```
function getRadioValSnake()
{
    snakecolor=($('input[name="snakecolor"]:checked').val());
    return snakecolor;
}

function getRadioValBg()
{
    bgcolor=($('input[name="bgcolor"]:checked').val());
    return bgcolor;
}

var snakecolorCurrent=getRadioValSnake();

alert(snakecolorCurrent)
```

Comment: thanks for your comment! strangely enough, when i use this in my code, it just throws out an alert with undefined as its value 2 times. also, i may have failed to mention that i need to get the value of a currently checked radio button as in what the user selects, this threw out the colour where checked="checked" attribute is present

Comment: it just throws out an alert with undefined.. sure because of  ` alert(snakecolorCurrent) ` and `undefined` because you do not have checked checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

one way is to pass the variable in function to other.js file and do whatever you want in other.js For example,

---------ColorSettings.js-----------

function getRadioValSnake()
{
    `snakecolor = $('input:radio[name="snakecolor"]:checked').val();
    fromcolorsettings(snakecolor);`

}

----------other.js----------------

function fromcolorsettings(scolor)
{
        
    `alert(scolor);--do whatever you want here`

}